# groupby 1 column and sum of other columns as new dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i have a pandas dataframe:

```
id    won    lost  match
v1     1       0     1
v1     2       1     3
v1     0       5     8
v2     3       1     7
v2     5       5     12
```

i want to groupby id and sum other columns such as i get a df

```
id    total_won    total_lost    total_match
v1      3              6             12
v2      8              6             19
```

How can i use pandas groupby and sum operation to sum multiple columns.
I tried using this:

```
pd.groupby('id')['won'].sum()
pd.groupby('id')['lost'].sum()
pd.groupby('id')['match'].sum()
```

is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) without define column - aggregate all [numeric columns](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#automatic-exclusion-of-nuisance-columns) to sum, then [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('id').sum().add_prefix('total_').reset_index()
print (df1)
   id  total_won  total_lost  total_match
0  v1          3           6           12
1  v2          8           6           19
```

If need specify multiple columns, add `list` of columns:

```
cols = ['won','lost']
df1 = df.groupby('id')[cols].sum().add_prefix('total_').reset_index()
print (df1)
   id  total_won  total_lost
0  v1          3           6
1  v2          8           6
```