# How can I sum 2 columns with Pandas to get sales and quantity values for a third column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I have a dataframe that contains sales info.

| Animal | Quantity Sold | Total Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Panda | 3 | 15 |
| Fox | 1 | 5 |
| Bear | 2 | 10 |
| Panda | 1 | 5 |
| Fox | 1 | 5 |

I want to get the total quanity and sales for each animal so the end output i would want is:

| Animal | Quantity_Sold | Total_Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Panda | 4 | 20 |
| Bear | 2 | 10 |
| Fox | 2 | 10 |

How can I achieve this? I can get the sum of either quantity or sales and aggregate the animal by using the following:

```
df2 = df[['Animal', 'Quantity_Sold', 'Total_Sales']]
df2 = df2.groupby('Animal')['Total_Sales'].agg('sum')
df2
```

How do I sum both and have the animals aggregate?
Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [groupby 1 column and sum of other columns as new dataframe pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45323914/groupby-1-column-and-sum-of-other-columns-as-new-dataframe-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

Just don't slice:

```
df2.groupby('Animal', as_index=False).sum()
```

Or directly from `df`, slice the columns to aggregate:

```
df.groupby('Animal', as_index=False)[['Quantity Sold', 'Total Sales']].sum()
```

output:

```
  Animal  Quantity Sold  Total Sales
0   Bear              2           10
1    Fox              2           10
2  Panda              4           20
```

Answer (score 1):

You're very close. Just select both columns before you aggregate.

```
df2 = df[['Animal', 'Quantity_Sold', 'Total_Sales']]
df2 = df2.groupby('Animal')[["Quantity_Sold", 'Total_Sales']].agg('sum')
```

Output:

```
        Quantity_Sold  Total_Sales
Animal                            
Bear                2           10
Fox                 2           10
Panda               4           20
```